# Do struct/classes somehow affect memory padding?

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, memory-alignment

Following code wth 2 questions:

```
struct Value
{
  int value
}

void main()
{
  Value v1;
  Value v2;

  int a;
  int b;

  return 0;
}
```

1) Why is the memory adress of my variables stored in functions downwards?

 v1 -> 0x00007fff5fbff758
 v2 -> 0x00007fff5fbff750

But for example in my struct they are stored in the other direction?
e.g. if Value had another variable int value_2;

v1.value -> 0x00007fff5fbff750
v2.value_2 -> 0x00007fff5fbff754

2)
why are int a and int b contiguous in memory and why isn't v1 and v2 contiguous in memory.

Is there any sort of alignment im unaware of?

Edit:

Coming back to this after a year.
After relearning the basics of assembly this makes much more sense now.
My advice for anyone who is interested in the underlying layout etc. Revisit asm after you learned C++, it's really interesting.

Comment: C or C++? they are different and C doesn't have `class`es.

Comment: You can have padding or not, variables can be stored in any order. All this is totally implementation dependent.

Comment: There is no `value_2` in your code.

Comment: a reason to use a higher level language is that you need not be aware of any sort of alignment (in most cases)

Comment: In C++, the order which objects of automatic storage duration within a scope are laid out is unspecified. padding between them is also unspecified.

Comment: The stack grows downwards.  Compilers allocate struct members at increasing offsets.  This is not otherwise nailed down in any standard, compilers *do* sometimes have a good reason to rearrange local variables.

Comment: @MichaelWalz i wrote "if" Value had another variable

Comment: @HansPassant ok, i was kinda suprised about that but now it make sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is the compiler that determines the order in which the variables are stored. There may not be a particular reason why, though in functions variables are stored on the stack in push-down order so if v1 is pushed first, then v2 it makes sense that v2 is 'below' v1.

In contrast, the order within a struct must follow the declaration (it is somewhere in the C specification). The reason is that a struct may overlay an array or other memory mapped area, where you want to make sure the variables are in a particular order and alignment.

2) Not sure, but the compiler may decided to align structures to 8 byte boundaries for optimization (you seem to use a 64 bit compiler, so 8 bytes is a 'natural' alignment).

Comment: the 8byte alignment seems to be true, because if i add more variables to the structure and it exceeds the 8bytes it will be 16byte aligned

but why is this alignment different to the alignment in the structure?
as far as i know in structures variables are aligned to the 'biggest type'

Comment: Does this 8byte alignment also affect cache lines?
since my object only uses 4 bytes but is 8 byte aligned(for optimization) it actually wastes space for cacheline right?

Comment: You can assume cache lines are optimized for the register width, or vice versa that the structure is optimized for your cache line. But this is all part of the dark voodoo that is called "compiler optimization" :) And yes, you may waste 4 bytes but performance will be better. There are probably __pragma__ options to force a smaller structure, if you need to.

Comment: if we take std::array and C-Array which should have the same performance, but std::array is easier to use. std::array would actually have an slight overhead due to the object memory alignment when its used. Even if we would never notice the overhead, this small overhead is still there right?
(this is just an example)